# How to enable event bubling from nested canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am drawing shapes on `Canvas`. I am using mouse events to do some action.
I draw rectangle with right mouse click, unfortunately when I release mouse on rectangle, no `MouseUp` event is fired.

### ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=img}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Cross" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                    <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseReleasedHandler" TargetObject="{Binding}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsDrawingEnabled}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

### DataTemple for Rectangle

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type over:RectangleROI}">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"
                   Fill="{Binding Fill}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"  
                   Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
                   />
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

#### My research:

- I've used [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) to sniff event.
- I could see event is fired on `Rectangle` item
- I could also see event is bubbling up (`Rectangle` -> `Canvas` -> `ContentPresenter`)
- **In all cases event wasn't marked as handled**

**UI structure snippet from [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) (sorry for image quality):**

[image: Snoop snippet]

#### What I've tried

- I saw some post which adviced to set:

  - `Canvas` background to transparent
  - Explicitly set `Width` & `Height`
- I've tried it on both Canvases

#### My current solution

I've I attached `EventTrigger` to `Rectangle`

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp" >
    <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseReleasedHandler" TargetObject="{Binding DataContext , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

I don't like this solution because I think there has to be better way.

#### My question

What I should do to enable event bubbling from Content presenter up to second (main) `Canvas` (ItemsControlItemPanel)

Comment: The `Canvas` that wraps the `Rectangle` is redundant. The panel is already a `Canvas`. The event bubbles up tree automatically. Maybe your EventTrigger is not working. Try to attach a common routed event handler to see if this gets invoked.

Comment: Also note that the DataContext of the ItemPaneltemplate is inherited from the ItemsControl - maybe your EventTrigger is disabled due to the binding that failes to resolve..

Comment: Sometimes it's far simpler to add a regular eventhandler in code behind that calls methods on a viewmodel. This action is user input so the front end aspect is not something i'd expect to exercise an automated test on. You could isolate a viewmodel and invoke a method or command on that to test the vm.  Which leaves the view "knowing" about a viewmodel as the downside. You could abstract with an interface. Or not bother if you felt this to be rather academic.